# join sql query to get additional column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like below

```
select caseId, name, totalCases from (select case_id as caseId, sub_case_name as name, count(*) as totalCases  from case_hist where upload_id = 110
group by caseId, sub_case_name)
```

Output looks like

```
caseID  name    totalCases
100780  TEST2   5
100780  TEST1   6
```

I have another query like:

```
select count(*) as caseMemebersCount from users where role_id = 40 and status = 1 and id in(select id from user_cases where case_id = 100780)
```

Output of this query is:

```
caseMemebersCount 
3
```

I want to format or join these 2 queries in sucha way that output is as follows:

```
caseID  name    totalCases  caseMemebersCount 
100780  TEST2   5           3
100780  TEST1   6           3
```

So join condition would be such that each rows case_id would be the input to the 2nd query. So 100780 has 3 caseMembers and 100800 has 5 caseMembers as below....

```
caseID  name    totalCases  caseMemebersCount 
100780  TEST2   5           3
100780  TEST1   6           3
100800  TEST    10          5
100800  SUB     16          5
```

Comment: how are the tables related? can you share the DML of the tables used in the queries for others to assist you?

Comment: @ EJ Egyed case_id in the history table is linked to case_id in user_cases table and id in users table is linked to id in user_cases table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to join your aggregates:

```sql
select v1.caseId, v1.name, v1.totalCases 
    ,v2.caseMemebersCount
from (
    select 
        case_id as caseId, 
        sub_case_name as name, 
        count(*) as totalCases  
    from case_hist 
    where upload_id = 110
    group by caseId, sub_case_name
    ) v1
    left join (
        select
            uc.case_id as caseId,
            count(*) as caseMemebersCount 
        from users u
             join user_cases uc
                on u.id = uc.id
        where 
            u.role_id = 40 
        and u.status = 1 
        group by uc.case_id
    ) v2 
    on v1.caseId = v2.caseId;
```